# Which is the easiest API for providing calendar feature for desktop application using java

Tags: java, swing, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

My client needs a feature of calendar(Remainder Type) which will be synchronized with my existing java software. Can I use any existing software and API for the same?

Comment: Need Calendar on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to synchronize with google calendars - I think, using googles own API is the best way to go.

- [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/?hl=de)

Comment: Google Calender Works fine on desktop?